# How to iter through multiple child nodes

Tags: python, arrays, json

My Json looks like this:

```json
{"orders":
    [
        {
            "id": "f7w0KvbCMln8snSrNuPm5H2t2GSZY",
            "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
            "line_items":
            [
                {
                    "uid": "1",
                    "catalog_object_id": "WYS7RWMA6SUCB4KATZBTT4MI",
                    "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "name": "Make Your Own Version [3 Options MAX]",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money":
                    {
                        "amount": 1775,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "modifiers":
                    [
                        {
                            "uid": "2",
                            "base_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Rice",
                            "catalog_object_id": "OGTP54WS4RUEVDIDRNOMVR3R",
                            "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "3",
                            "base_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Grilled Chicken",
                            "catalog_object_id": "RG5P5P73YQ5CHJ23UWTGK3TU",
                            "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                        {
```

How do I iter through the array and get name": `"Rice"`,`"catalog_object_id"` from the modifiers object?

I tried

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'modifiers', ['name', 'catalog_object_id'], 
                    record_prefix='modifiers')df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'modifiers', ['name', 'catalog_object_id'], 
                    record_prefix='modifiers')
```

Comment: Why use pandas for this?  Just use `json.loads` and iterate through `for order in data['orders']:` / `for item in order['line_items']:` / `for mod in item['modifiers']:` / `print(mod['name'], mod['catalog_object_id'])`.

Comment: This breaks when I add more data such as:

Comment: {
      "id": "rbNESXcolEjzzUXTCkdOCGHkcRcZY",
      "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
      "line_items": [
        {
          "uid": "1",
          "catalog_object_id": "6DKJE7LB6IZ4ZRL6LCS6V5ZG",
          "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
          "quantity": "2",
          "name": "Lemongrass Chicken Soup",
          "variation_name": "Regular",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 1775,
            "currency": "CAD"
          },

Comment: "modifiers": [
            {
              "uid": "2",
              "base_price_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
              },
              "total_price_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
              },
              "name": "Rice Noodles",
              "catalog_object_id": "THNRPUH447QAPTCPL5ZMJU5E",
              "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
              "quantity": "1"
            }
          ],

Comment: Why does it break?  That's exactly the same format.

Comment: I mean it only fetches the first record and then stops.What may be the issue

Comment: MY code does not stop after the first record.  You either need to update the question or ask a new question with the code you really have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this with a series of nested loops or with a comprehension. I prefer the comprehension when it can be written cleanly and in this case it can.

**given: (updated with new data)**

```py
data = {
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": "f7w0KvbCMln8snSrNuPm5H2t2GSZY",
            "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
            "line_items":
            [
                {
                    "uid": "1",
                    "catalog_object_id": "WYS7RWMA6SUCB4KATZBTT4MI",
                    "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "name": "Make Your Own Version [3 Options MAX]",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money":
                    {
                        "amount": 1775,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "modifiers":
                    [
                        {
                            "uid": "2",
                            "base_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Rice",
                            "catalog_object_id": "OGTP54WS4RUEVDIDRNOMVR3R",
                            "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "3",
                            "base_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money":
                            {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Grilled Chicken",
                            "catalog_object_id": "RG5P5P73YQ5CHJ23UWTGK3TU",
                            "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "rbNESXcolEjzzUXTCkdOCGHkcRcZY",
            "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
            "line_items": [
                {
                    "uid": "1",
                    "catalog_object_id": "6DKJE7LB6IZ4ZRL6LCS6V5ZG",
                    "catalog_version": 1682294620871,
                    "quantity": "2",
                    "name": "Lemongrass Chicken Soup",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money": { "amount": 1775, "currency": "CAD" }, 
                    "modifiers": [
                        {
                            "uid": "2",
                            "base_price_money": { "amount": 0, "currency": "CAD" },
                            "total_price_money": { "amount": 0, "currency": "CAD" },
                            "name": "Rice Noodles",
                            "catalog_object_id": "THNRPUH447QAPTCPL5ZMJU5E",
                            "catalog_version": 1682294620871, "quantity": "1"
                        }
                     ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then this:

```py
results_a = []
for order in data["orders"]:
    for item in order["line_items"]:
        for mod in item["modifiers"]:
            results_a.append((mod["name"], mod["catalog_object_id"]))
```

or this

```py
results_b = [
    (mod["name"], mod["catalog_object_id"])
    for order in data["orders"]
    for item in order["line_items"]
    for mod in item["modifiers"]
]
```

when printed should both result in:

```
[
    ('Rice', 'OGTP54WS4RUEVDIDRNOMVR3R'),
    ('Grilled Chicken', 'RG5P5P73YQ5CHJ23UWTGK3TU'),
    ('Rice Noodles', 'THNRPUH447QAPTCPL5ZMJU5E')
]
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as I add:
{ "id": "rbNESXcolEjzzUXTCkdOCGHkcRcZY", "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF", "line_items": [ { "uid": "1", "catalog_object_id": "6DKJE7LB6IZ4ZRL6LCS6V5ZG", "catalog_version": 1682294620871, "quantity": "2", "name": "Lemongrass Chicken Soup", "variation_name": "Regular", "base_price_money": { "amount": 1775, "currency": "CAD" },

Comment: "modifiers": [ { "uid": "2", "base_price_money": { "amount": 0, "currency": "CAD" }, "total_price_money": { "amount": 0, "currency": "CAD" }, "name": "Rice Noodles", "catalog_object_id": "THNRPUH447QAPTCPL5ZMJU5E", "catalog_version": 1682294620871, "quantity": "1" } ],

Comment: Breaks how? If you have a new test case like this please add Ir to the original question as an edit

Comment: I mean the additional data i just added is a new record in the transaction table. When I combine both and do the extraction, it gives the following outcome:

Comment: Rice OGTP54WS4RUEVDIDRNOMVR
Grilled Chicken RG5P5P73YQ5CHJ23UWTGK3TU
Grilled Pork KK3OS355GUSA4QXGCE2SFELK
Spring Roll R2WVQVITIAZRS6JB63QBTEIL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b16e61ef59c0> in <cell line: 2>()
      5     for order in data['orders']:
      6         for item in order['line_items']:
----> 7             for mod in item['modifiers']:
      8                 print(mod['name'], mod['catalog_object_id'])
      9 

KeyError: 'modifiers'

Comment: @Aiss, I added your new data and assuming I added it where it looked naturally to go these solutions work fine.